# Binomial probability mass function with confidence interval

Tags: r, statistics, confidence-interval

The following question we need to solve.

Consider the following `binomial probability mass function (pmf)`:

`f(x;m,p) = (m¦x) p^x * (1-p)^(m-x)`, for `x = 0, 1, 2,.....,m,`
and otherwise equal to `0`. Let `X_1, X_2,....,Xn` be independent and identically distributed random samples from `f(x;m = 20; p = 0:45)`.

1) Assume n = 15 and calculate the 95% confidence interval on p using the  `p-hat = Σ_(i=1)^n X_i/mn` (an estimator of p). Simulate these confidence intervals 10000 times and
count how often the parameter value p lies within these 10000 confidence intervals.

```
m <- 20
p <- 0.45
n <- 15
x <- m
nsim <- 10000
counter <- 0

for (i in 1:nsim) {
  bpmf <- rbinom(x,m,p)
  esti_p <- bpmf/(m*n)
  var_bpmf <- var(bpmf) 
  CI_lower <- esti_p - qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(var_bpmf/n) 
  CI_upper <- esti_p + qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(var_bpmf/n) 
  if ((CI_lower<p) & (CI_upper>p)) counter <- counter + 1
}
```

**It doesn't work properly and I don't see what I'm doing wrong. Is there anyone who can help me with this?**

When I run my code, I believe the answer now is right, but it gives the following sentence: "There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)" When I run this it will give:

```
"1: In if ((CI_lower < p) & (CI_upper > p)) counter <- counter +  ... :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used".
```

Also I don't know for sure if;

```
 CI_lower <- esti_p - qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(var_bpmf/n) 
 CI_upper <- esti_p + qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(var_bpmf/n)
```

is the right formula to calculate the confidence interval.

Comment: you're not actually *simulating* anything here as far as I can see ... do something with `rbinom()` rather than `dbinom()` ?

Comment: What error does it give... can you add it in the question?

Comment: oh that worked out, I changed the dbinom to rbinom and removed the brackets from bpmf/(m*n) because that would give a weird output either, but now when I run my code it will give over 50 warnings. Is this normal?

Comment: When I run the code multiple the counter will be around 250/300 does this seems like a good output? Thanks for helping btw!

Comment: take a closer look at the arguments you are giving to `rbinom()` (hint: the first argument should be a single value, not a vector ...)

Comment: I guess you are talking about the x value, if I change it to only 'm' I get the  same results.

Comment: I put the brackets back, because that should be the formula I realised

Answer (score 0):

```
m <- 20
p <- 0.45
nsim <- 10000

  bpmf <- rbinom(size=m,prob=p,n=nsim)
  esti_p <- bpmf/m
  var_bpmf <- esti_p*(1-esti_p)/m 
  CI_lower <- esti_p - qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(var_bpmf) 
  CI_upper <- esti_p + qnorm(0.975)*sqrt(var_bpmf) 
  counter <-((CI_lower<p) & (CI_upper>p))
table(counter)
```